# Logging into Pokemon Go through Pokemon Trainer Club API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, pokemon-go

I was checking out this old Pokemon Go project which makes a map of all nearby pokemon: [text](https://github.com/modrzew/pokeminer) and wanted to see if it still works. There are some syntax things that have changed since the original project was made but I managed to make it run.

It seems like it uses Pokemon Trainer Club to log into accounts and then conduct a "scan" of the map, but I keep getting error messages about the program not being able to do so, so I'm wondering if it's because Niantic changed the login process completely, or if it's just because this is an old project.

Here's the function in the file titled "worker.py" which seems to try the login:

```
def login_ptc(username, password):
    logger.info('PTC login for: %s', username)
    head = {'User-Agent': 'Niantic App'}
    session = local_data.api_session
    r = session.get(LOGIN_URL, headers=head)
    try:
        jdata = json.loads(r.content)
    except ValueError:
        logger.warning('login_ptc: could not decode JSON from %s', r.content)
        return None
    # Maximum password length is 15
    # (sign in page enforces this limit, API does not)
    if len(password) > 15:
        logger.debug('Trimming password to 15 characters')
        password = password[:15]

    data = {
        'lt': jdata['lt'],
        'execution': jdata['execution'],
        '_eventId': 'submit',
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
    }
    r1 = session.post(LOGIN_URL, data=data, headers=head)

    ticket = None
    try:
        ticket = re.sub('.*ticket=', '', r1.history[0].headers['Location'])
    except Exception:
        logger.debug('Error: %s', r1.json()['errors'][0])
        return None

    data1 = {
        'client_id': 'mobile-app_pokemon-go',
        'redirect_uri': 'https://www.nianticlabs.com/pokemongo/error',
        'client_secret': PTC_CLIENT_SECRET,
        'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
        'code': ticket,
    }
    r2 = session.post(LOGIN_OAUTH, data=data1)
    access_token = re.sub('&expires.*', '', r2.content)
    access_token = re.sub('.*access_token=', '', access_token)
    return access_token
```

Here is basically what shows up in the file titled "worker.log":

```
[2023-12-22 19:12:34,911][MainThread][    INFO][L 661] Starting up!
[2023-12-22 19:12:34,912][MainThread][    INFO][L 607] Worker (re)starting up!
[2023-12-22 19:12:34,914][  worker-0][    INFO][L 289] PTC login for: freq010
[2023-12-22 19:12:34,915][MainThread][    INFO][L 607] Worker (re)starting up!
[2023-12-22 19:12:34,915][  worker-1][    INFO][L 289] PTC login for: freq011
[2023-12-22 19:12:34,915][MainThread][    INFO][L 607] Worker (re)starting up!
[2023-12-22 19:12:34,915][  worker-2][    INFO][L 289] PTC login for: freq012
[2023-12-22 19:12:34,915][MainThread][    INFO][L 607] Worker (re)starting up!
[2023-12-22 19:12:34,916][  worker-3][    INFO][L 289] PTC login for: freq0013
```

`[2023-12-22 19:12:35,075][  worker-3][ WARNING][L 296] login_ptc: could not decode JSON from b'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">\n<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">\n<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>\n</HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>403 ERROR</H1>\n<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>\n<HR noshade size="1px">\nRequest blocked.\nWe can\'t connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.\n<BR clear="all">\nIf you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.\n<BR clear="all">\n<HR noshade size="1px">\n<PRE>\nGenerated by cloudfront (CloudFront)\nRequest ID: aX5fHDwjp7eNQUAyFKO3hCi11F4xhATUPanZvyZM3MbiKRtHx0k1wA==\n</PRE>\n<ADDRESS>\n</ADDRESS>\n</BODY></HTML>'`

```
[2023-12-22 19:12:35,075][  worker-3][    INFO][L 382] Could not login to PTC - sleeping
```

...And after that it just repeats forever. I'm certain that all the login information is correct and that the rest of the program runs fine. Is this error because of some new security change to Pokemon Trainer Club logins, or is it fixable?

Any help would be appreciated!